# JREngage for Phonegap does not compile

Tags: cordova

I have followed the instructions as mentioned in the link in order to include JREngage plugin to my Phonegap based Xcode project. But when I compile, i get the error JRCaptureUser.h not found. The plugin itself doesnt have a such header file but it is being imported in all the other plugin files.

[Here](http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/mobile-libraries/phonegapcordova/) is the link to instructions.

Comment: Hi Baxethov. Did you manage to solve that error?. I'm currently having the same issue when trying to add JREngage to XCode. Any fix?

Comment: Hi rmvz3. Follow the posts on this link. Janrain team is working on it. [JREngage issue](https://community.janrain.com/entries/22141482-jrcaptureuser-h-file-not-found?page=1#post_22830601)

Comment: rmvz3! I am now facing issue while using Engage with Phonegap 2.1. It does compile but Cordova doesnt find the plugin on runtime. Do let me know if you happen to sort it out. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I was using JREngage in Cocoa, not Phonegap. I just found another version of JREngage (in GitHub if I remember right) that doesn't included JRCapture nor the other Janrain classes and it worked correctly without any other intervention. Sorry for not been more helpful.